# Default property value with closure makes a compiler to recompile all files

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal, swift3, xcodebuild

This [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) has a paragraph **Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function** where we can find an example

> Here’s a skeleton outline of how a closure can be used to provide a default property value:
>
> ```
> class SomeClass {
>
>     let someProperty: SomeType = {
>          // create a default value for someProperty inside this closure
>          // someValue must be of the same type as SomeType
>          return someValue
>     }() 
> }
> ```

Well, I use it very often... Also, I often wait for the whole project to recompile after changing just one symbol. And today I have discovered that these two things are associated to each other.

Lets imagine we have some class where we set some default properties with a closure and with a function

```
class Class1 {
    
    let value: Int
    
    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    private lazy var lazyValueWithClosure: Int = {
        return 1111
    }()
    
    private lazy var lazyValueWithFunction: Int = self.getValue()
    
    private func getValue() -> Int {
        return 2222
    }
}
```

Also we have some other class in a separate file where we use the above `Class1`

```
class Class2 {
    
    let value: Int
    
    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
        _ = Class1(100)
    }
}
```

And some other class in a separate file where we use `Class2`

```
class Class3 {
    
    let value: Int
    
    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
        _ = Class2(100)
    }
}
```

and etc...

I've decided to use `terminal` + `xcodebuild` + `grep` to get only info about recompiled files. That is the command I use to get compilation info:

```
xcodebuild -scheme Test -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -configuration Debug build OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" | grep '^[0-9]\{1,20\}.[0-9]\{1,20\}ms.*init(_ value: Int)'
```

That is all for preparations. Now we go to `Class1` and change `2222` to some other value. Run the above command and get a result.

```
0.1ms   /Users/iwheelbuy/Documents/recompile/Test/Classes/Class1.swift:11:5 init(_ value: Int)
```

The result is good. Setting default value with functions works as expected. We have changed one file and only one file was compiled.

Then lets change the value `1111` from the `Class1` to some other value and run the command. Terminal output now looks like this:

```
0.8ms   /Users/iwheelbuy/Documents/recompile/Test/Classes/Class5.swift:11:5 init(_ value: Int)
0.3ms   /Users/iwheelbuy/Documents/recompile/Test/Classes/Class1.swift:11:5 init(_ value: Int)
1.0ms   /Users/iwheelbuy/Documents/recompile/Test/Classes/Class4.swift:11:5 init(_ value: Int)
0.3ms   /Users/iwheelbuy/Documents/recompile/Test/Classes/Class3.swift:11:5 init(_ value: Int)
0.3ms   /Users/iwheelbuy/Documents/recompile/Test/Classes/Class2.swift:11:5 init(_ value: Int)
```

All the classes were recompiled... Now imagine that you have a large project and any small change in a default value closure makes you wait for the whole project to recompile.

Questions:

- What is the reason?
- Any suggestions how to use default value closures and not to suffer from recompilation?
- Related to [this topic](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62737?start=0&tstart=0)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known problem in the Swift compiler. The issue is that once you use closures or lazy properties like this, every single Swift file will be type checked. I've written a blog post on this topic which you can find [here](https://medium.com/p/37b0a7514cbe).